# Creating calculations in an existing session

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, session

i'm currently developing a shopping application with AngularJS, PHP, a webservice and some html/css and XML.

i'm currently working on the cart session and i've stumbled upon some problems creating the total price, total item count and VAT calculations.

So the session is written in PHP. The code is as following:

```html
<?php

session_start();

$product_id = $_REQUEST['product_id'];
$product_name = $_REQUEST['product_name'];
$product_price = round($_REQUEST['product_price'], 2);
$product_size = $_REQUEST['product_size'];
$product_quantity = $_REQUEST['product_quantity'];
$total_product_price = $product_price*$product_quantity;
round($total_product_price, 2);
$total_items = $_SESSION['cart'][$product_quantity];
// Add new item to session
$cartProduct = array(
    "id" => $product_id,
    "name" => $product_name,
    "price" => $product_price,
    "size" => $product_size,
    "quantity" => $product_quantity,
    "total_price" => $total_product_price,
    "total_items" => $total_items
);

/*
 * check if the 'cart' session array was created
 * if it is NOT, create the 'cart' session array
 */
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

// check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
if(array_key_exists($product_id and $product_size, $_SESSION['cart'])){
    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
    echo "<script> alert('Dit product staat al in de winkelwagen')</script>])";
}

// else, add the item to the array
else{
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]=$cartProduct;
}
```

As the code above states all the information about the product is requested. the requested items like the `product_id` are then set into an `array()`. the `array()` is, after some checks, added to a sessoion: `$_SESSION['cart'];`. My there are no problems adding and showing the cart. The problem i'm having is with creating the calculations necessary to show the total_items in the cart, the total_price of the cart and the VAT calculation.

If more info is needed please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be due to you using the session before it may have been created? `$total_items = $_SESSION['cart'][$product_quantity];`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code this is the issue I see

```
$total_items = $_SESSION['cart'][$product_quantity];
```

Because

```
  $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]=$cartProduct;
```

And

```
  $cartProduct =    array(
    "id" => $product_id,
    "name" => $product_name,
    "price" => $product_price,
    "size" => $product_size,
    "quantity" => $product_quantity,
    "total_price" => $total_product_price,
    "total_items" => $total_items
);
```

So if you have a `$product_quantity` of `3` then you are pulling `$product_id` '3' out which makes no sense.  Because for example if we have `$product_id` of `6` and `$product_quantity` of `3` then:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][6] = array(
    "id" => 6, //$product_id,
    "name" => $product_name,
    "price" => $product_price,
    "size" => $product_size,
    "quantity" => 3, //$product_quantity,
    "total_price" => $total_product_price,
    "total_items" => $total_items
);
```

So why would we pull out the quantity and not the product id, follow.

The only thing seasonable here in stead of`$_SESSION['cart'][$product_quantity]` is

```
$total_items = $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['total_items'];
```

But I think you may also have other issues, because what is the purpose or difference between `$product_quantity` and `$total_items` ?  wouldn't the total items be the quantity of product.  Or is one the number of total products ( count of unique Product IDs ), and one the number a that specific product ( qty of one Product ID ).  If that is the case tracking the total number of all products in each product is unnecessary and error prone.

Your also accessing the session potentially before assigning the product to the cart, here

```
 $total_items = $_SESSION['cart'][$product_quantity];
```

This is probably wrong too

```
 array_key_exists($product_id and $product_size, $_SESSION['cart'])
```

AS I get this when testing something similar

> Warning:  array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

This is probably because  `$product_id and $product_size` evaluates to `true` from doing a Boolean comparison there.

Just my assessment.

Comment: i would like to get the total amount of different id's not the total qunatity. i was aware of the `array_key` but i didn't see the issue in this case since it isn't something that has somehting to do with my question. My question is: How can i count the different product id's and show them as: you have .. items in the cart. And i would like to calculate the total cart price and VAT price. That's where my issue is. Thank you for the tips about the session since some of them are very usefull but it doesn;t answer my question